# Configuring to read RTC at boot time

Tags: boot, i2c, rtc, system-clock, ds1307

I have added an RTC to the I<sup>2</sup>C bus of the Raspberry Pi. If I follow the steps mentioned [here](http://www.susa.net/wordpress/2012/06/raspberry-pi-pcf8563-real-time-clock-rtc/) (I am using the DS1307 RTC IC), I can run `hwclock` and read the time.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# modprobe rtc-ds1307
root@raspberrypi:~# echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/new_device
```

Once, I run this, I cannot access the RTC from my python script any more. However, I have to do this at each boot. Is there a way I can specify my RTC address on the I<sup>2</sup>C so than the system recognizes it at boot time?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 4):

Add the commands to `/etc/rc.local` for the module to be loaded on each boot.

Depending on your distrobution, the path to `rc.local` may vary. On Arch ARM it is `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

You may want to add an echo command before the module is loaded for some visual feedback, for example:

`/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo Loading RTC module
modprobe rtc-ds1307
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/new_device
echo Done
```

Keep in mind that `rc.local` runs last - after all other init scripts have run, so if you have anything else at boot that depends on the hwclock being set, be sure to run those *after* `rc.local` has run, ideally append it after the last `echo` command above.

If you really need to have the hwclock set earlier, you'll need to edit one of the init scripts in `/etc/rc.d` (or wherever they are located on your distro) to load your module and echo commands.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment, and I will point it to the answer if/when I find one... Have spent hours on this today.

The OP approach appears to be obsolete due to this change : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=97314  which means that a large amount of advice on forums about the RTC doesn't apply any more.

I've been able to get 'hwclock' working by enabling I2C and drivers using raspi-config (turn on I2C and drivers, in 'advanced settings') and then add 
`dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307` to the bottom of /boot/config.txt

So great, hwclock appears to then work  and read and write the clock. But you then need to make changes so that 'fake-hwclock' is removed and replaced by proper reading of the hwclock at startup.

This is a good guide on that - although details for a different RTC. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=842661#p842661

But it doesn't seem to apply to 2015-05-05-raspian-wheezy, the lines to be  commented out in /lib/udev/hwclock-set are not there. For me, by the time /etc/rc.local is executed, one of the existing startup scripts has already corrupted the RTC somehow.

This is the kind of issue that conventional forums are really bad for - there's lots of good advice that applied in 2012, and then a long series of ifs and buts and you may collect the updated truth eventually. I can't find a *direct* question to this issue - how to install an RTC for raspian - on this SE, so I'll ask it, and end up pointing this there.

---

UPDATE: See [How to install Real Time Clock (RTC) on Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38186/how-to-install-real-time-clock-rtc-on-raspian/38304)